# Fetch items where related rows has different values

Tags: mysql, join, select, mysql-5.6

I have table in MySQL called `attributes`, and other table, `attribute_values`, one attribute can have multiple values, values identified by `context` attribute and has `value_c` attribute wich contain value. It means like I have one attribute for 5 different contexts, and I want fetch only those attributes where `value_c` is different. I know how to fetch all of them but how add comparison? Can somebody help me? Thanks!

Comment: Could you please add some example data (5-10 rows) and expected results? Or prepare a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Comment: key-value stores have problems.  Your schema sounds like key-value on steroids.  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.